# How to assign alfresco activiti workflow task to intersection of two or more groups?

Tags: workflow, alfresco, activiti

I'm developing alfresco activiti workflow and i want to assign a task to users who simultaneously are in two specific groups. Separating groups by comma in *activiti:candidateGroups* gives the union of groups. Is it even possible to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to setup some service task / or some execution listener before getting to your user task to assign to your set of users, and there you should be using [this](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/references/API-JS-getMembers.html) and [this](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/references/API-JS-getContainerGroups.html) to fetch your groups and their underlying users.

```
var group1 = people.getGroup("GROUP_DUMMY");
var g1Users = [];
if(group1){
   g1Users = g1Users.concat(people.getMembers(group1));         
}

var group2 = people.getGroup("GROUP_SAMPLE");
var g2Users = [];
if(group2){
   g2Users = g2Users.concat(people.getMembers(group2));         
}
```

Once you do so, you should setup a new array to contain only users that belong to both groups, but instead of putting the user nodes, you should be putting `user.properties.userName` instead.

**You must have a String array with each and every value representing a username !**

And finally export that array to your execution like this `execution.setVariable('scwf_candidates', users);` setup your user task like this:

```
<userTask id="..." name="My Task" activiti:candidateUsers="${scwf_candidates}">
</userTask>
```